# REPLACE INTO SET without specifying column for the values

Tags: mysql

Can I replace all values on a row using REPLACE INTO without specifying the specific columns to update like you can on an INSERT INTO?

Example

This works:

```
REPLACE INTO `product` SET id = 13,`condition`='new'
```

This doesn't work but I want to do something like this:

```
REPLACE INTO `product` SET id = 13 VALUES('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12','13','new');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can just use the same syntax as for the `INSERT INTO` case:

```
REPLACE INTO product SELECT '1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12','13','new'
```